# Install keras and tensorflow using Rstudio

Tags: python, r, windows, tensorflow, keras

While trying to following the instructions of installing Keras and TensorFlow on Rstudio link https://keras.rstudio.com/index.html I get the following error.  It is a work computer that is running Windows 7.  I am not familiar with python, but I believe I have python 3.6 installed correctly (I am able to run simple python code in the Spyder IDE).  Thanks in advance for any suggestions on how to get this working.

```
> install_keras()
Creating r-tensorflow conda environment for TensorFlow installation...
Solving environment: ...working... failed

CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url 
<https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/noarch/repodata.json.bz2>
 Elapsed: -

An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your 
way.
ConnectionError(MaxRetryError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='repo.continuum.io', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /pkgs/main/noarch/repodata.json.bz2 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000000000474D860>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed',))",),)


Error: Error 1 occurred creating conda environment r-tensorflow
In addition: Warning message:
running command '"C:\Users\...\...\Local\CONTIN~1\ANACON~1\Scripts\conda.exe" "create" "--yes" "--name" "r-tensorflow" "python=3.6"' had status 1
```

Comment: I tried it myself and it was working. From the error message, it might be an Internet connectivity issue. Try a few more times.

Comment: You may need to get your IT people to solve firewall or other barriers.

Comment: Thanks.  I tried it several more times, but it still gives the same error.  My internet is working, but maybe their is some setting I need to change?  As far as IT help I asked them too, but they are not familiar with R, python, keras, etc. so it makes it difficult.

Comment: IT did say that port 443 is blocked, so I am wondering if that is the problem?  Is their a way to install keras and tensorflow without using this port?  Thanks.

Comment: "*port 443 is blocked*" That's not your issue.  Port 443 is allocated for *incoming* HTTPS requests on a server, but the error you are seeing has to do with not being able to connect to a remote server on *its* port 443 using HTTPS.  On Mac or Linux, things like this come up when `openssl` or `RCurl` are not installed/up-to-date.  But you're on Windows, so...not sure.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Installing Keras and TensorFlow using install_keras() isn't required to use the Keras R package. You can do a custom installation of Keras (and desired backend) as described on the Keras website and the Keras R package will find and use that version.

[Source](https://keras.rstudio.com/reference/install_keras.html#custom-installation)

So you can circumvent this issue with the firewall using a custom installation. The R package `keras` will then find that installation automatically. See the linked source for more information on how to do a custom installation.

**edit:** btw, there is a similar question that has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46803208/install-keras-in-rstudio-fails-with-http-connection-error). That poster goes into changing the proxy settings to cicrumvent the firewall. I cannot mark this question as a duplicate due to active bounty.

Comment: Thanks.  I ended up going the approach outlined in the other question you mentioned in the link.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you first update your conda in terminal:

```
conda update --all
```

Then run the following commands in R:

```
install.packages("tensorflow")
library(keras)
to_categorical(0:3)
```

You could also test the followings if you get any error at the time of installing tensorflow and keras:

```
install.packages("tensorflow")
install.packages("keras")
install_keras()
install_tensorflow()
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a good answer here:

https://github.com/rstudio/keras/issues/649

(scroll down to the answer by skeydan)

**Here is the answer:**

First install tensorflow directly from GitHub, as in

```
devtools::install_github("rstudio/tensorflow")
devtools::install_github("rstudio/keras")
```

Then do

```
tensorflow::install_tensorflow()
tensorflow::tf_config()
```

which should give you version 1.12.

We have been installing TF 1.10 until yesterday because of a bug in that will only be fixed     in TF 1.13 (which should be out anytime but unfortunately isn't yet). Now with people     having installation problems due to incompatibilities with numpy as installed by conda, we     decided to switch to TF 1.12 now and as soon as TF 1.13 is actually available, we'll     install that by default.

If you still run into problems installing, please open another issue and describe the problem, indicating the output of

```
reticulate::py_discover_config()
reticulate::use_condaenv("r-tensorflow")
reticulate::py_config()
```

Thanks!